# Zigbee CC2531 sniffer successfully installed, but no working device found

Tags: linux, wireshark

On my Linux iMac I have flashed 2 x CC2531 Zigbee dongles successfully (I believe), following this manual: https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/advanced/zigbee/04_sniff_zigbee_traffic.html

I needed to install this extra package, which was not mentioned in that manual:

```
apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

It's Ubuntu 22.04 on an iMac from 2013.

They seem to work:

```
lsusb | grep -i cc
Bus 003 Device 033: ID 0451:16a8 Texas Instruments, Inc. CC2531 ZigBee
Bus 003 Device 031: ID 0451:16a8 Texas Instruments, Inc. CC2531 ZigBee
```

Still, whsniff gives a "ERROR: No working device found."

```
/usr/local/bin/whsniff -c 20
ERROR: No working device found.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working via a colleague. He says it is this one :

https://www.ti.com/tool/PACKET-SNIFFER

sniffer_fw_cc2531.hex

- It is 23190 bytes on my system. Just make sure you have that one. That was the only one that worked for me. Since it is not my software and it is proprietary, I can't publish it. Contact me if you can't find it.

Comment: Glad you got it working! It's not apparent to me what you do with this hex file; could you [edit] your answer to say a bit more? Thank you!